# How to check selected time is less than current or greater than current time using angular 8

Tags: angular, angular10

Im working on appointment project in that i want to check appointment time with current time `this.appointmentFromTime <=  this.timeNow && this.appointmentToTime >= this.timeNow` but in this condition time is getting as string so code is not working as expected `this.timeNow = formatDate(this.today, 'h:mm a', 'en-US', '');`

Comment: could you reproduce on stackblitz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to work with string dates it to convert them into a `Date` object. Then, you can easily run your comparison by doing `date.getTime() > date2.getTime()`

```js
const dateString = '2020-09-24T16:57:23.985Z';

console.log('current time is greater', new Date().getTime() > new Date(dateString).getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

above method is wokring good but making it simple we can use this

```
let currentDateTime = new Date();
this.officeStartTime = new Date();
this.officeStartTime.setHours(7, 0, 0); // 7.00 am
this.officeEndTime = new Date();
this.officeEndTime.setHours(19, 0, 0); // 7.00 pm
if (this.officeStartTime <= currentDateTime && this.officeEndTime >= currentDateTime) {
  const source = interval(3600000); // one hour in milliseconds
  const text = 'Status Update';
  this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => this.refreshStatus(text));
}
```

also we can able to convert any date and time format using new Date and check the condition `const dateString = '2020-09-24T16:57:23.985Z'; const dateStr = new Date(dateString); const currentDateTime = new Date(); console.log('current time is greater', dateStr > currentDateTime);`